A rocket problem solved using momentum conservation law
Suppose a rocket is fired upward with initial mass $m_0$ and it emits gas with mass rate $\alpha$ (.i.e $\frac{dm}{dt} = \alpha$). If $V$ is the gas speed in relative to the rocket, find the rocket speed. Assume that there's gravitational force acting.
This was the problem I encountered with, but my question is a little bit more general.
Let us denote $m_r, v_r, m_g, v_g$ to be the mass and speed for rocket and gas respectively s.t $v_r, v_g$ denote the speeds with absolute value then we can write:
$v_g = V - v_r$
and if $a_r, a_g$ are the acceleration vectors for the rocket and gas respectively then: $a_g = \frac{d(-v_g)}{dt} = \frac{d(v_r - V)}{dt} = \frac{dv_r}{dt} = a_r $.
So we can write the change of momentum for the gas as
$\frac{dp_g}{dt} = -\frac{dm_g}{dt}v_g + m_ga_r$
summing with rocket's change of momentum yields:
$-m_0g = -\frac{dm_g}{dt}V+m_0\frac{dv_r}{dt} \implies dv_r = (\frac{dm_g}{dt}\frac{V}{m_0} - g)dt$
However, integrating this yields a solution that is incorrect (it is not equal to the known formula which involves the use of the logarithm function).
I'd like if someone could help me figure the point where I fail to think logically, thanks

It is the rocket which should be of primary concern rather that the emitted gas.
Instead of using $m_{\rm r}$ and $v_{\rm r}$ for the rocket I will just use $m$ and $v$.
Let the rocket momentum at some time $t$ be $m\,v$.
At a later time $t+dt$ the momentum of the rocket and exhaust gases is $(m-dm)(v+dv) + dm(v-V) = m\,v + m\,dv -dm\,V-dm \,dv$ and the last term can be neglected as a second order term.
So the change in momentum in is time $dt$ is $(mv + m\,dv -dm\,V) - m\,v= m\,dv-dm\,V$ and the rate of change of momentum is $m \frac{dv}{dt} - \frac{dm}{dt}\,V$.
You then wrote $\dots$ summing with rocket's change of momentum $\dots$ and changed $m$ to $m_0$ which I assume was the initial mass of the rocket and this is where you made a mistake.
You need to do an integration from initial mass is ${m_0}$ to final mass at time $t$ is $m$ and not just change $m$ to $m_0$.
With no external forces the rate of change of momentum is zero so $m \frac{dv}{dt} - \frac{dm}{dt}\,V=0$ and if you need to add an external force acting of the rocket system then add a term on the right-hand side of the equation.
If you want the external force to be thee gravitational force then you must use m,g$ where $m$ is the mass of the rocket and so is not constant and also get the sign right.
The rocket equation is derived in many sources on the internet, eg Variable Mass Systems: The Rocket Equation.
